# Getting NaN result when performing a calculation using variables from HTML form (Java)

Tags: java, servlets, nan

I'm trying to calculate a monthly car loan payment using values submitted through an HTML form which are passed to a servlet which uses a Java class to come up with an answer. Every time I run the form I'm getting NaN as a result.

Form:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Car Loan</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Car Loan Calculator</h1>

    <form method = "get" action = "CalcPayment">
        <label> APR: </label><input type ="text" name ="apr"><br>
        <label> Term (in years): </label><input type ="text" name 
         ="term"><br>
        <label> Principal: </label><input type ="text" name 
       ="principal"><br>

        <input type="submit" value ="Get Loan Payment">
     </form>
    <p>
       Loan payment is: ${carLoan.getPayment()}
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Servlet:

```
@WebServlet(name = "CalcPayment", urlPatterns = {"/CalcPayment"})
public class CalcPayment extends HttpServlet {


@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse 
response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    String strApr = request.getParameter("apr");
    String strTerm = request.getParameter("term");
    String strPrincipal = request.getParameter("principal");
    int apr, term;
    double principal; 
    CarLoan loanPay;


        apr = Integer.parseInt(strApr);
        term = Integer.parseInt(strTerm);
        principal = Double.parseDouble(strPrincipal);


    loanPay = new CarLoan (apr, term,  principal);


    request.setAttribute("carLoan",loanPay);
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp").forward(request, 
response);        
 }

}
```

Object:

```
package pojos;

public class CarLoan {
private int apr, term;
private double principal;


public CarLoan (){
    this.apr = 0;
    this.term = 0;
    this.principal = 0;
}

public CarLoan(int apr, int term, double principal) {
    this.setApr(apr);
    this.setTerm(term);
    this.setPrincipal(principal);
}

public double getApr() {

    return apr;
}

public void setApr(int apr) {
    if(apr >= 0 && apr <= 30){
       this.apr = apr;         
    }
    else{
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("APR must be between 0 and 
30");
    }
}


public double getTerm(){
    return term;
}

public void setTerm(int term) {

    if(term>=1 && term<=6){
       this.term = term*12;  
    }
    else{
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Loan term must be between 1 
"
                + "and 6");
    }
}


public double getPrincipal(){
    return principal;
}

public void setPrincipal(double principal) {

    if(principal>=0){
       this.principal = principal;  
    }
    else{
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Principal amount cannot be  
+ "negative");
    }
}


public double getPayment(){

    double r = ((this.apr/100)/12);
    double denominator = (Math.pow(1+r, this.term) - 1);
    double numerator=  (r * Math.pow(1 + r, this.term));

    return (numerator/denominator);
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return String.format("rate= %d term=%d principal=%.2f", this.apr, 
            this.term, this.principal,+ this.getPayment());

}
}
```

Comment: It would be easier for us to help you if you could tell us on what line in your code you get NaN and what input you used at the time.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in the last line of getPayment(). If both denominator and numerator are 0.0, you will get the NaN error.

You can try it out by temporarily returning a fixed value to see if the NaN error persists.